# Using jQuery and Math.random() to select nested objects properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, javascript-objects

I'm creating a random quote machine that will present a random quote from various philosophers.

I have an object literal with nested objects containing philosophers and their quotes. Using jQuery functions and Math.random(), how can I select a random quote from my object literal structure? Is there a better way to organize the data?

I've started with a jQuery closure that will display a designated quote that I'd like to modify using Math.random().

Looking for explanations to solutions as I'm a beginner. Thanks in advance.

Example object literal:

```
var quotes = 
{
  awatts: {
    name: "Alan Watts",
    quote: "The only way to make          sense out of change is to            plunge into it, move with it,        and join the dance."
  },
  etolle: {
    name: "Eckhart Tolle",
    quote: "Realize deeply that the       present moment is all you ever       have."
  },
  tmckenna: {
    name: "Terrence Mckenna",
    quote: "“The cost of sanity in        this society, is a certain          level of alienation” "
  }
};
```

Example jQuery functions with single quote selected:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.mybutton').click(function() {
            $('#quote').html(quotes.awatts.quote);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of the data seems fine. You could use an array, but an object isn't a problem.

You'd get the keys from the object, and then pick a random key

```js
var quotes = {
  awatts: {
    name: "Alan Watts",
    quote: "The only way to make          sense out of change is to            plunge into it, move with it,        and join the dance."
  },
  etolle: {
    name: "Eckhart Tolle",
    quote: "Realize deeply that the       present moment is all you ever       have."
  },
  tmckenna: {
    name: "Terrence Mckenna",
    quote: "“The cost of sanity in        this society, is a certain          level of alienation” "
  }
};

$('.mybutton').click(function() {
  var keys = Object.keys(quotes);
  var rand = keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)];
  $('#quote').html(quotes[rand].quote);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="mybutton">Quote</button>
<br><br>
<div id="quote"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks adeneo. This solution works great for me! Really appreciate the prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

If you can make your `quotes` object an array, the following would do the trick. Change your array

```
var quotes = [
  {
    name: "Alan Watts",
    quote: "The only way to make          sense out of change is to            plunge into it, move with it,        and join the dance."
  },
  {
    name: "Eckhart Tolle",
    quote: "Realize deeply that the       present moment is all you ever       have."
  },
  {
    name: "Terrence Mckenna",
    quote: "“The cost of sanity in        this society, is a certain          level of alienation” "
  }
];
```

Set the max and min (to set the upper and lower limits for the random number)

```
var max = quotes.length, min = 0;
```

Generate a random number

```
var rand = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
```

On the click event use the random number to choose your random quote

```
$('#quote').html(quotes[rand]quote);
```

I have not tested the code. Hope this will get you going :-)